# Closing nested Reader

Tags: java, file-io, stream, resource-management, try-finally

When reading from a text file, one typically creates a `FileReader` and then nests that in a `BufferedReader`. Which of the two readers should I close when I'm done reading? Does it matter?

```
FileReader fr = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
try
{
    fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    // ...
}
finally
{
    // should I close fr or br here?
}
```

I'm a little paranoid when it comes to exception-safety. What happens when the `BufferedReader` constructor throws an exception? Does it close the nested reader? Or is it guaranteed not to throw?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, `close()` on the outermost stream wrapper will call `close()` on the wrapped streams. However, if you think it's likely that a constructor will throw an exception, make liberal use of the [Closeable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface.

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
Closeable res = fr;
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    res = br;
} finally {
    res.close();
}
```

So, even if the JVM ran out of heap space for the buffer and threw an error, you wouldn't leak a file handle.

For Java 7 and above use try-with-resources:

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
  // do work
}
```

Comment: Good solution if you're working with multiple possibly exception-throwing wrappers (and similar). Of course, you could check the documentation and code of the `BufferedReader` to see if there's actually any chance of an exception in the ctor.

Answer (score 1):

Closing only the `BufferedReader` is enough, cause it wraps the `FileReader`. If you look at the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedReader.java.html) of `BufferedReader` you will see that the `close` method, closes the wrapped stream.

Answer (score 0):

Close the BufferedReader in a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the BufferedReader's close method, the BufferedReader will call the FileReader's close method. Thus both close method's are called. More precisely the BufferedReader will do nothing *BUT* calling the FileReader's close method. Thus it does not matter at all. Though I think it is good practice too call the BufferedReader's close method.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is guaranteed not to throw.  Because the buffer is allocated it may throw OutOfMemoryError.  I usually separate my code into 2 sections: acquire resources and then use resources.  Each section usually has unique cleanup needs

Here is the code to illustrate:

```
// Acquire resources section.

final FileReader fr = new FileReader( fileName );

BufferedReader br = null;

try
{
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);
}
finally
{
    if ( br == null )
    {
        // Note that you are closing the fr here
        fr.close( );
    }
}

// Use resources section
try
{
    // ... use br
}
finally
{
    // Now that br is safely constructed, just all its close
    br.close( );
}
```

And I agree with you, there is nothing worth than silently loose a file handler in the long running server application.